# mocking open/file in for loop

Tags: python, mocking

Consider mocking an open call returning a file object

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> mock_fi = MagicMock()
>>> mock_op = MagicMock()  
>>> mock_op.return_value = mock_file
>>> 
>>> f = mock_op()
>>> f is mock_fi
True
```

So far so good. The contents of mock_calls are

```
>>> mock_fi.mock_calls
[]
>>> mock_op.mock_calls
[call()]
```

and that is fine too. Now consider looping over lines in the file

```
>>> for l in mock_fi:
...     break
... 
>>> mock_fi.mock_calls
[call.__iter__()]
```

and that is as expected. What I do not understand is why the mock_op object has recorded an `__iter__` call too

```
>>> mock_op.mock_calls
[call(), call().__iter__()]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, [mock_calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls) records all the calls to the object, and to the objects returned by calls on that object.

For example:

```
>>> my_mock = MagicMock()
>>> my_mock.foo().bar()
<MagicMock name='mock.foo().bar()' id='140397146563528'>
>>> my_mock.mock_calls
[call.foo(), call.foo().bar()] # bar() was not called directly on my_mock,
                               # yet, it is included since it was called on 
                               # the return value of foo() which is a direct 
                               # access to my_mock
```

In the original code, `mock_op.mock_calls` reports `call().__iter__()` which is the call to `__iter__()` on `mock_fi`.